# Monotonicity of an iterated integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the following function $f(n)$

$$f(n)=\int_0^1\ldots\int_0^1 \exp\bigg({-}\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\big)^{-1}\bigg)\, dx_1\ldots dx_n.$$

Does $f(n)$ increase with $n$?

Answer (score 2):

One has
$$
\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i}<\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}x_i}, \qquad 0<x_i<1, \tag1
$$ giving
$$
e^{\Large -\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i}}>e^{\Large -\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}x_i}}\tag2
$$ integrating $(2)$ over $[0,1]^n$ gives
$$
\int_{[0,1]^n}e^{\Large -\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i}}dx_1 \cdots dx_n>\int_{[0,1]^n}e^{\Large -\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}x_i}}dx_1 \cdots dx_n \tag3
$$ then integrating $(3)$ over $[0,1]$ with respect to $x_{n+1}$ yields
$$
\int_{[0,1]^{n+1}}e^{\Large -\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i}}dx_1 \cdots dx_{n+1}>\int_{[0,1]^n}e^{\Large -\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}x_i}}dx_1 \cdots dx_n \tag4
$$ that is
$$
f(n+1)>f(n), \qquad n\ge1.
$$ This suggests a conjecture.

> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,1]^n}e^{\Large -\frac{1}{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}x_i}}dx_1 \cdots dx_n =1. \tag5
> $$